# How to create a text slide in animation with CSS?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

So I am trying to create a `text reveal` / `text-slide-in` animation.

I've created this:

```css
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }

  100% {
    left: 105%;
  }
}

.text-slide-in:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 105%;
  animation: slide 1.5s ease infinite;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px white, 0 0 10px white, 0 0 5px white;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="text-slide-in">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h1>
```

And that is precisely the effect/animation I am after. The problem is that this basically creates an uneccesary width. You can see the horizontal scrollbar on the snippet.

The other problem with this approach becomes clear when adding a `background-color` to the parent element:

```css
.site-wrap {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

section {
  padding: 4rem;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: red;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
  }

  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
}

.text-slide-in {
  position: relative;
}

.text-slide-in:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  animation: slide 1.5s ease infinite;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px white, 0 0 10px white, 0 0 5px white;
}
```

```html
<div class="site-wrap">
    <section>
      <h1 class="text-slide-in">
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
      </h1>
    </section>
  </div>
```

As you can see, it will not work when a `background-color` is set.

I've also tried doing this with `transform` & `translateX` css properties, but I cannot get that to work either.

What would be a solid solution in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use clip-path:

```css
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    clip-path: inset(0 100% 0 0);
  }
  100% {
    clip-path: inset(0    0 0 0);
  }
}

.text-slide-in {
  animation: slide 1.5s ease infinite;
}

body {
 background:linear-gradient(90deg,red,lightblue);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="text-slide-in">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could animate the width and start your position on the right instead of animating the left:

```css
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
  }

  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
}

.text-slide-in:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  animation: slide 1.5s ease infinite;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px white, 0 0 10px white, 0 0 5px white;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="text-slide-in">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you! That partly solved my problem. I just found another bug. With the current animation I cannot add a background-color. Could you have another look at it please?

Comment: if you have a background colour, you should add the same background colour to your pseudo element - ie everywhere you use white, change it to be the same, otherwise you can use Temani's answer as you don't need a pseudo element to cover the text